# VMWare Workstation REST API - Как отправить PUT запрос?

Tags: c#, rest, виртуальная-машина, vmware

### Требуется написать программу, взаимодействующую с виртуальными машинами VMWare через API.

GET запросы отправляются корректно и приходит правильный ответ:

**GET** *http://127.0.0.1:8697/api/vms* =>

```
[
  {
    "id": "UCVPUUKT6F0KOCTU7COFUFDDEPTOG8UQ",
    "path": "C:\\Virtual\\Windows 10 and later x64.vmx"
  }
]
```

А вот с PUT запросом уже проблема:

**PUT** *http://127.0.0.1:8697/api/vms/UCVPUUKT6F0KOCTU7COFUFDDEPTOG8UQ/power* =>

```
{
  "Code": 9,
  "Message": "Content type not supported"
}
```

**Формирование тела запроса:**

```
var body = JObject.FromObject(new
{
    operation = "on"
}).ToString();
```

**Код отправки запросов:**

```
internal string BaseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8697/api/";

internal string MakeRequest(HttpMethod method, string route, string body = "")
{
    string content;
    try
    {
        HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {
            string ur = $"{BaseUrl}{route}";
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, ur);

            if (body != "") request.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/vnd.vmware.vmw.rest-v1+json");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic <-АВТОРИЗАЦИЯ->");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.vmware.vmw.rest-v1+json");

            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
            response = client.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return $"{e}";
    }

    return content;
}
```

За помощь в решении задачи готов предложить денежное вознаграждение, а то упёрся в тупик и не знаю что делать с этой проблемой. Технических ошибок я не наблюдаю. Думаю, что проблема в `Content-Type` тела запроса, но он правильный, исходя из документации. Если требуется ещё какая-либо информация о проблеме - отвечу.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Судя по [этому](https://developer.vmware.com/apis/412/vmware-workstation-pro-api/#api) и [этому](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/17/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-2444C276-63D9-4F7F-918D-42D4923E81E1.html), вы должны либо отправить на `/api/vms/{id}/power` простой текст (один из предложенных статусов), например `on` (а вы отправляете JSON `{"operation" = "on"}`), либо на `/api/vms/{id}` (не `power`) отправить уже JSON `{"operation" = "on"}`.

Comment: Переданный тип контента не поддерживается в запросе, возможно сервер ждёт например `text/plain`, а не вот это вот всё.

Comment: _`.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` не делайте так никогда. Это просто зло. И так `.Result` доя незавершённых задач тоже не днлайте. Используйте `async/await`, иначе проблема с типом контента - не самое страшное, что может пойти не так. И ещё вот это `new HttpClient` - клиент надо создавать один раз на всё время работы приложения, а не на каждый запрос. Об этом даже написано в официальной документации по нему. Еще `JObject.FromObject` - Newtonsoft.Json устарел._

Comment: 1, 2. Ошибка была не из-за этого, но спасибо за замечание. 3. Спасибо за советы. Чем сейчас пользуются вместо `JObject.FromObject`?